# How can i solve "Multiple Sqflite Save" problem on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I'm doing an e-commerce-like application. When the user likes a product, I save it with sqflite on another page called my favorites.But the problem is that the more the user presses the button, the more it saves.
[image]

```
 GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async{
              Client rnd = Client(lastName: degerVer(widget.numUrunOzel));
              await DBProvider.db.newClient(rnd);
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.favorite))
```

[image: First is my product page, Second is my favorites page.]

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to check if object exists in db, if yes update, else add a new object

1. using [conflict algo](https://pub.dev/documentation/sqflite_common/latest/sql/ConflictAlgorithm-class.html)

You can just insert all your data to the table setting the ConflictAlgorithm to replace or ignore

`db.insert(table, data, conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);`

2. Query, compare, replace/update

quite expensive to use.

`db.query(table, columns: availableColumns, where: 'columnToQueryBy = ?', whereArgs: [queryParam]);`

Comment: i can try but i didn't

Comment: @EDMGL didnt understand your comment